My brave browser will crash on launch
Description of the issue:
I was using a switch emulator at the same time i had my brave browser open, my pc froze for two seconds and brave crashed. Now Brave will launch but after a second it will shut down even though the switch emulator isn't open. Iv tried to update brave but it didn't help.
How can this issue be reproduced?

Launch Brave
The program runs in the activities bar but then instantly shuts down.

Brave Version( check About Brave):
Brave Browser 126.1.67.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Additional Information:
This is the error message I get in terminal.
$ brave-browser
[0620/180332.410412:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180332.410453:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180332.605777:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180332.605806:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[21334:21334:0620/180332.862390:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[21334:21334:0620/180332.936519:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[0620/180333.043948:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180333.043974:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[21334:21356:0620/180333.105383:ERROR:nss_util.cc(345)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
[21334:21334:0620/180333.154998:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[0620/180333.273973:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180333.273993:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[21334:21334:0620/180333.363195:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[0620/180333.456078:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180333.456092:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[21334:21334:0620/180333.537391:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[0620/180333.604052:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180333.604066:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[21334:21334:0620/180333.686336:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[0620/180333.756926:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180333.756939:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
[21334:21334:0620/180333.838519:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=139
[21334:21334:0620/180333.838532:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(449)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
[0620/180333.845346:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0620/180333.851912:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/bff72149-1f8c-4e39-8508-b1741aa2e96c.lock: File exists (17)
[0620/180333.851932:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(153)] open /home/user/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/pending/eacc9020-7104-49f3-ad77-88dfe88b8026.lock: File exists (17)
/usr/bin/brave-browser: line 48: 21334 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "$HERE/brave" "$@"

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2

Starting point is what OS & release you're using, ie. details of your software stack. What are you running?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
This is the only info i can get about the browser since it wont start up  Brave Browser 126.1.67.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Im only running the browser its the official build and should be the newest version

Please add additional details to your question (this is a Q&A site and not a forum, answers will be to your question itself, comments are from readers commenting about the question and will be deleted once addressed in question).  Your last paste shows your system is very behind on applying security fixes & package updates which maybe your problem. You can view https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ to show when 22.04.3 ISO was released; but installed systems upgraded before that date, and you've not yet applied fixes since 2023-August, so do so asap.
